# How to look at a for loop within a for loop the pythonic way

Tags: python, for-loop, combinations, python-itertools

I found this code from itertools.product to find unique combinations of lists

```
args = [["a","b"], ["a", "c", "d"], ["h"]]
pools = [tuple(pool) for pool in args]

for pool in pools:
    result = [x + [y] for x in result for y in pool]
```

which gives:

```
print(result)
[['a', 'a', 'h'], ['a', 'c', 'h'], ['a', 'd', 'h'], ['b', 'a', 'h'], ['b', 'c', 'h'], ['b', 'd', 'h']]
```

Now I'm wondering if there is a way to write this in a 'normal' way with for loops? I managed to rewrite it for a single for loop with if statement, like below:

```
[s for s in p if s != 'a']
```

equals:

```
s = []
for x in p:
    if x != 1:
        s.append(x)
```

But I haven't managed to do this for a for loop within a for loop... I'm pretty new to this, so I'm guessing there has to be some way of doing this but I don't see how. Does anyone how to do this?

Comment: You can just put one for loop nested inside another, just like how in your last example the `if` is inside of the `for`.

Comment: Actually you have to reverse their order, too, so the last one becomes the first `for`, etc.

Comment: Thanks! So how would that work for this [x + [y] for x in result for y in pool]. I don't quite get how to get the x + [y] appended in the right way...

Answer (score 0):

I think you can continue the trend, for example:

```py
[(x,y) for x in [0,1,2,3,4,5] if x < 3 for y in [0,1,2,3,4,5] if 2 < y if x + y == 4]
```

is equivalent to (by taking every `for` and `if` and putting them on a new line):

```py
s = []
for x in [0,1,2,3,4,5]:
    if x < 3:
        for y in [0,1,2,3,4,5]:
            if 2 < y:
                if x + y == 4:
                    s.append((x,y))
```

For the example in the question, the `result` inside the list comprehension refers to the old value of `result`, so need to keep that value around while creating the new `result`:

```py
result = [[]]
for pool in pools:
    old_result = result # remember the old result
    result = [] # build the new result with this variable
    for x in old_result:
        for y in pool:
            result.append(x + [y])
```

Alternatively, you can build the new `result` in a different variable and set `result` to it:

```py
result = [[]]
for pool in pools:
    new_result = [] # build the new result with this variable
    for x in result:
        for y in pool:
            new_result.append(x + [y])
    result = new_result # update our current result
```

There is also another example [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

Comment: Thanks! So how would that work for this [x + [y] for x in result for y in pool]. I don't quite get how to get the x + [y] appended in the right way....

Comment: @Ablu_68 I've updated the answer to show that example. As to why they append in the right way, that is because first, we have `result = [[]]`, then we go through the first `pool` (`["a","b"]`) and append that to everything in `result`, giving us `[["a"], ["b"]]`. Then we append each of the elements in the second `pool` (`["a", "c", "d"]`) onto each element in `result`, giving us `[["a", "a"], ["a", "c"], ["a", "d"], ["b", "a"], ["b", "c"], ["b", "d"]]`, and so on. Hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: @Winstone Yess this was exactly what I was looking for! It makes perfectly sense, I feel kind of stupid now for not seeing it myself.. :) Thank you!